# Как сделать импорт формул, формата, шрифта в другую таблицу?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Есть одна основная таблица, она дублируется и каждый сотрудник пользуется своей отдельной таблицей, чтобы не мешать друг другу, так как вкладки взаимодействуют друг с другом.

Проблема в том, что та таблица постоянно дорабатывается и нужно чтобы формулы, цвет заливки, шрифт и пр. изменения из основной таблицы автоматически переносились во все копии, потому что сейчас когда что то нужно исправить, приходится заходить отдельно в каждую из них и делать одно и то же действие.

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли какая то формула которая импортирует не значения, а формулы и пр. данные или если нет, то какой макрос можно прописать??